# Duplicate entry error for composite unique key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert data in a table which has the following columns :

```
id, date, client, device, user
```

I have created a *primary key* on *id* and *unique key* on the combination of *client, device, and user*.

While inserting data I getting the following **Error**:-

```
Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate entry '200-217-Xiaomi-M200' for key 'uk_user_client_device'
```

I checked the data in the table using the following query using:-

```
SELECT user, client, device, COUNT(1) rowcount FROM mytable GROUP BY user, client, device HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

This got an empty set in response so I am certain there are no duplicate keys in the table.

I also went through the logs and I found that the data was inserted in the table at the same time I got this error. So, the data was inserted yet I got the duplicate entry error.

I also confirmed that this doesn't happen always. Sometimes, the data is inserted without any issue and sometimes I get an error and the data is inserted anyway.

I've seen a few questions regarding this with no definitive answer. I'm unable to figure out why this error is being thrown.

Comment: Have you checked triggers on this table?

Comment: There are no triggers, I've verified

Comment: Can you show a single `INSERT` statement which reproduces this problem? You may be doing a double-insert for some reason. This can be caused by something as simple as someone double-clicking something, or your code firing the same function twice by accident.

Comment: Of course your query gives empty result - now there is no duplicates in a table. But when you try to insert duplicated value then error occures - and again no duplicates in a table. When you receive shown error message execute `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (client, device, user) = ('200-217', 'Xiaomi', 'M200')` (maybe I'm wrong in columns order) and ensure that this row is already present in a table.

Comment: @Akina Worth noting this could be inside a transaction, in which case it could be rolled back and no such record is committed.

Comment: @tadman When unique constraint violation detected the insertion will be rolled back anycase.

Comment: @Akina Yeah. I just mean to point out that even though "nothing is there" that because of MVCC there could have been a short-lived record that caused the problem.

Comment: @tadman I see. But this short-lived row must be inserted in the same connection. Or dirty reads must be allowed.

Comment: @Akina We need to see more code, especially the Java doing the insertion, to understand more.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

Of course this query returns no rows:

```
SELECT user, client, device, COUNT(1) as rowcount
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user, client, device
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

You have specified that `client`/`device`/`user` is a *primary key* (or at least unique.  Hence, there are no duplicates.  The database enforces this.

If you attempt to insert a row that would create a duplicate, the database returns an error.  The row is not inserted.  The database ensure the data integrity.  Yay!

Your error is saying that the data in the insert either duplicates existing data in the table.  Or, if you are inserting multiple rows, then the data has duplicates within the `insert`.

You can solve this in multiple ways.  A typical method is to ignore the insert using `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into mytable ( . . . )
     . . .
     on duplicate key update user = values(user);  -- this is a no-op
```

The database prevents duplicates from being inserted.  This construct prevents an error -- although no duplicate rows are inserted, of course.